# Getting a DNS TXT record in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dns

I need to get the txt field from the DNS record.
Is there any ruby api to do something like this?

```
nslookup -q=txt xxxx.com
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try installing the [dnsruby](https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby) gem.

The code is actively maintained, and used in some significant production systems.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dnsruby'
include Dnsruby

# Use the system configured nameservers to run a query
res = Dnsruby::Resolver.new
ret = res.query("google.com", Types.TXT)
print ret.answer
```

(Code tested on MacOS X - prints the Google SPF record)

See also @Alex's answer which is more idiomatic Ruby - Alex is the author of `dnsruby`.

Comment: Link is not work. Use this [link](https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby)

Answer (score 22):

Use the Ruby stdlib `Resolv::DNS` library without installing a gem:

```
require 'resolv'
txt = Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
  records = dns.getresources("_dmarc.yahoo.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT)
  records.empty? ? nil : records.map(&:data).join(" ")
end
#=> "v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:dmarc-yahoo-rua@yahoo-inc.com, mailto:dmarc_y_rua@yahoo.com;"
```

`getresources` returns an array of instances of the requested record class name (`Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT`). Here, I return nil if the TXT record(s) or the host name were not found, otherwise I map over the records, call `data` to get the values, then join them together.

Any DNS record type [TXT, NS, CNAME, MX, ...] can be queried as well by replacing TXT in the above example.

TXT records are "unstructured" and used for enhanced data for the hostname such as SPF, DKIM, DMARC configurations.  In practice, there may be only one TXT record, but the RFC doesn't say how many there can be.

Read the docs at: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Good to see someone suggest a built-in solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
require 'dnsruby'
Dnsruby::DNS.open {|dns|
  dns.each_resource("google.com", "TXT") {|rr| print rr}
    # or
  print dns.getresource("google.com", "TXT")}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby provides "Resolv" a thread-aware DNS resolver library. Resolv can handle multiple DNS requests concurrently without blocking the entire Ruby interpreter.

**For getting DNS MX records**

```
require "resolv"
    Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
      ress = dns.getresources "infoir.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX
      p ress.map { |r| [r.exchange.to_s, r.preference] }
    end
```

**For getting DNS A records**

```
require "resolv"
    Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
      ress = dns.getresources "infoir.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A
      p ress.map { |r| [r.exchange.to_s, r.preference] }
    end
```

**For getting DNS TXT records**

```
require "resolv"
Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
  ress = dns.getresources "infoir.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT
  p ress.map { |r| [r.exchange.to_s, r.preference] }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Net::DNS](http://github.com/bluemonk/net-dns/) gem.

Here is an example:

```
result = Net::DNS::Resolver.start("google.com", Net::DNS::TXT)
values = result.each_mx.map { |r| r.txt }
# "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all "
```

Further instructions for installation and usage can be found on the Github page linked above.

Comment: i tried using  Net::DNS::Resolver.start("waycoolblog.com", Net::DNS::TXT). but i count get the value for the txt field. 
how should i be actually using it??

Comment: I think you're using it correctly, but it seems broken and doesn't actually return the TXT record as it should. Sorry.

Answer (score -3):

Or use system("nslookup -q=txt xxxx.com")

Comment: am thinking of not using with system() as it might be very expensive.

Comment: It won't be expensive compared to the cost of a DNS lookup

Comment: This would only work on Unix-like systems, not on windows or devices. Its not a good solution for most production applications, but works well enough for one-off scripts. @nfm: This method will be more expensive as you must fork a process, run the command, and still do the DNS lookup.