# How to retrieve the IP address of another website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ip-address, httparty

I need to retrieve the IP address of some of my websites from a main dashboard in Rails, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Googling so far has only returned answers on how to get the IP address of visitors.

I'm using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to parse the pages, can I use these requests to find out the IP somehow?

Comment: Use a DNS lookup, using whatever ruby's equivalent of `gethostbyname('www.example.com')` is.

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913226/getting-a-dns-txt-record-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc B's comment I found [this simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742521/finding-the-ip-address-of-a-domain):

```
>> require 'socket' #=> true
>> IPSocket::getaddress("www.google.com") #=> "74.125.79.147"
```